# Let $A=[1 2 0 1 ]$. Find all $2×2$ matrices B, $B≠O_2$ and $B≠I_2$ such that $AB=BA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A=[1 2 0 1 ]$. Find all $2×2$ matrices B, $B≠O_2$ and $B≠I_2$ such that $AB=BA$

Explain your answer.

I know two ways to find B

A) As det of A is 1, it is invertible. So A = B (inverse)

B) Or by assigning a,b,c,d as four elements of B matrix and then solving for AB=BA

But the question says to find all 2×2 matrices B. Is there any way i can find all possible matrices for B such that AB=BA?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Just write down a matrix $B=(b_{ij})$ with $4$ coefficients and then compute directly. It is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

If $$B = \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}$$

From $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}          =  \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&2 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
 we have $$ a+2c = a\implies c=0$$

and $$b+2d = 2a+b \implies a=d$$

so $$B = \begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ 0&a \end{pmatrix}$$

Now you have two more equations, but from them you do not get any new information so we are done.

Comment: I actually solved the question till here. The other two equations cancel out giving zero?

Comment: Yes........................